# How to perform an NTLM challenge on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ntlm

I'm trying to access some web services in an iPhone application.

If I `GET` to the .asmx page, I authenticate and get the WSDL as expected.

However, if I `POST` to the .asmx page, setting the SOAPAction, Content-Type, Content-Length, and HTTPBody, I just keep getting `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` messages.

Additionally, I'm trying to POST to IIS using Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA), which means I'm trying to negotiate an NTLM challenge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I unfortunately found my answer. NSURLConnection cannot do NTLM authentication. Here's a post about how to do NTLM authentication using the CFNetwork stack.

[HTTP Post via the CFNetwork stack](http://jameswilliams.me/developer/blog/2008/08/http-post-via-the-cfnetwork-stack/)

Found something even better than doing all of that tediousness: Someone who has already done it!
[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-CFNetwork-wrapper-for-HTTP-requests)

**Update: There is a [workaround for iOS 4](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues#issue/52) that allows for NTLM authentication again**

Comment: Thanks! ASIHTTPRequest was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like your web-service has different read (get) and write (post) permissions.  I dont think this is an issue with the iPhone or NSURLConnection at all.

Comment: The web client works fine and if I create a .Net application, that works fine as well. But I guess I could check the permissions just in case.

Comment: The permissions for GET and POST are identical.

Comment: Are you sure?  Something the POST function is doing might require authentication such as writing to a file.  The .NET client is most likely authenticating for you.  Have you tried making the call in an HTTP Debugger?  http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/

Comment: HTTP Client exhibits the same behavior I'm experiencing even with GET. Constant authentication requests.

Comment: Further more, I am trying to authenticate every time it asks. And in the .Net and iPhone applications, I'm using the same credentials. So I don't see how one can somehow be authentication more than the other.