# Log into a NTLM server with CodeName One

Tags: codenameone

So I'm new to codename1, 
Im trying to log into a server using HTLM, 
How would I achieve this?

I cannot find any resources that help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTLM requires native support from the OS. What you did there will work on JavaSE where the simulator is running but will not work on the device.

To get this to work on the device you will need native code [NTLM Authentication with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968769/ntlm-authentication-with-httpurlconnection) describes how this is done for Android. To implement that you will need to create a native interface and call this code within the native interface:

```
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
```

From that point on the rest should work from Codename One. Notice that you will need to also place the [library that's required](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/) within the native/android directory.

The iOS side of the fence should work with this [how to send NTLM request in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226750/how-to-send-ntlm-request-in-ios)

Specifically this block:

```
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
initWithHost: _host
port: 80
protocol: @"http"
realm: _host
authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM];
```

Answer (score 1):

As found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.Authenticator;
    import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class RunHttpSpnego {
        static final String kuser = "username"; // your account name
        static final String kpass = password; // retrieve password for your account 

        static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
                // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
                System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
                return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```